# A list containing objects of two different classes in C++

Tags: c++, list, object

I feel more fluent in Java than C++ so I will try to explain what I want to "transport" in a few words. In `Java` you could create an `ArrayList` containing objects of 2 or more classes that one of them inherited from another. Let me illustrate. Let's say we have:

```
class Vehicle
{
...
}

class Car extends Vehicle
{
...
}
```

You could then do something like that `Car a = new Vehicle ([arguments]);`
And then you could add objects of both `Vehicle` and `Car` to the same `ArrayList` created as following:

```
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

Now to my problem, in C++ I have manually written the code to create a simple linked list. Each node of this list is described below:

```
struct clientListNode
{
    vip* cust;
    struct clientListNode* next;
};
```

`vip` is another class which is derived from `customer`.Is there any way to allow my list to accept both objects of `vip` class and `customer` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polymorphism works the other way. You can use a `customer*` pointer to point to a `vip` object, but not the other way. (This is related to the [Liskov-substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution).)

So if you had a `customer*` in your `clientListNode` class, it would accept both `vip*` and `customer*` pointers.

However, I don't think you should reinvent the wheel and implement a linked list from the ground. You should look into the **[STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)** (Standard Template Library) which already has solutions for problems like this. For instance, it already has an implementation of the linked list, [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).

You have to template `std::list` with the base type you'd like to use it with, but it is important that you cannot use the type directly as a value (`std::list<cust>`), because that would physically store cust instances in memory, in which you cannot fit the more specific `vip` type (slicing would occur).
Instead you have to use some kind of handle as the template parameter, you can use a native pointer (`std::list<cust*>`), but that way you have to manage memory deallocation, or - more preferably - you can use a smart pointer, like `shared_ptr` (`std::list<std::shared_ptr<cust>>`), that way the created objects are going to get destroyed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but in fact I DO have to reinvent the wheel, it's for a project of mine. That's for the constructive feedback though and for answering my question.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you could make Car = new Vehicle even in java, but the other way around makes sense.

What you're after is called "polymorphic collection". C++ standard lib does not have one out of the box, but you can approximate it with a collection of `shared_ptr<Vehicle>` s or `unique_ptr<Vehicle>` s. The former would fork very close to a java equivalent.

3rd party libraries may have ready to use polymorphic collections, you can use the term for search.

Answer (score 1):

If `customer` is the base class, then the `cust` field of the node should be of type `customer*`, and it will gladly accept both customers and vips.